# Get the coordinates of an ImageView in android

Tags: android

I have about 40 `Imageview widgets` inside a `RelativeLayout` in my Android application. The problem is that I want to get the exact coordinates of each `Imageview` because I want to swap to images using `onTouch`.

Comment: what did you try so far? also notice that there are tons of posts about how to get view coordinates

Answer (score 0):

```
yourImageView.getX();   
yourImageView.getY();
```

Comment: Thank, but i've tried it already but whatever where the image position is, the values of X and Y are zero

Comment: Then post some code, I'm sure someone here can figure out why

Comment: Float Xvalue = TempButton15.getX();

        MultiTouchListener touchListener=new MultiTouchListener(this);
        TempButton15.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

        tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

           tv.setText(Xvalue+"");
Xvalue is always equals 0.0